# Select All Elements With the First Letter of Their ID Being Equal to a Variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

`rank` is a variable equal to a one character capital string (EX: "A"). How do I select all `h1` elements within the div `nodeField` with an id beginning with `rank`? All `h1`s have a two character capitalized id, such as "AB". I understand this is a pretty simple question, but I couldn't find anything online regarding this problem.

```
$("#nodeField>h1[id^=rank]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the selector with the `rank` variable:

```
var rank = "AB";
var elements_with_id_matching_rank = $("#nodeField > h1[id^=" + rank + "]");
```